# How to prevent virtualenv to fork?

Tags: python, virtualenv, sudo, init.d

I have this situation where I start a virtualenv python script from an init.d service. Every time I `stop`, a process becomes 'orphan'. I tought that `kill`-ing the main process would kill all children. It does kill children, but not recursively. Let me show you:

I do `/etc/init.d/bit2euro` and these processes are started:

```
➜  ~ sudo /etc/init.d/bit2euro start
Starting bit2euro
➜  ~ ps -eaf|grep python
root       380     1  0 09:57 pts/0    00:00:00 sudo -u bit2euro venv/bin/python run_frontend.py
bit2euro   384   380  9 09:57 pts/0    00:00:00 venv/bin/python run_frontend.py
bit2euro   393   384 12 09:57 pts/0    00:00:00 /var/www/bit2euro/79/venv/bin/python run_frontend.py
dennis     400 32021  0 09:57 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn python
➜  ~
```

Now when I `/etc/init.d/bit2euro stop` :

```
➜  ~ sudo /etc/init.d/bit2euro stop
Stopping bit2euro...
Stopped
➜  ~ ps -eaf|grep python
bit2euro 32580     1  0 09:47 pts/0    00:00:02 /var/www/bit2euro/79/venv/bin/python run_frontend.py
dennis   32745 32021  0 09:55 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn python
➜  ~
```

Which means process 32580 has not been killed.

This is the part of the `init` script that starts it:

```
    echo "Starting $name"
    cd "$dir"
    if [ -z "$user" ]; then
        sudo $cmd >> "$stdout_log" 2>> "$stderr_log" &
    else
        sudo -u "$user" $cmd >> "$stdout_log" 2>> "$stderr_log" &
    fi
    echo $! > "$pid_file"
    if ! is_running; then
        echo "Unable to start, see $stdout_log and $stderr_log"
        exit 1
    fi
```

This is the stop part:

```
    echo -n "Stopping $name.."
    kill `get_pid`
    for i in {1..10}
    do
        if ! is_running; then
            break
        fi

        echo -n "."
        sleep 1
    done
    echo

    if is_running; then
        echo "Not stopped; may still be shutting down or shutdown may have failed"
        exit 1
    else
        echo "Stopped"
        if [ -f "$pid_file" ]; then
            rm "$pid_file"
        fi
    fi
```

I understand why but not how to fix it so that this process is killed too, or how to prevent this fork from happening in the first place

Comment: i recomend to use `start-stop-service` tool

Comment: I'm sorry @eri, I dont know what that is.